# How to delete files from blob container?

Tags: c#, azure

```
private readonly CloudBlobContainer _blobContainer;

public void Remove()
{
    if (_blobContainer.Exists())
    {
       _blobContainer.Delete();
    }
}
```

How to delete not a whole container but some `List<string> disks` that in the container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean an Azure storage Blob container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426213/how-to-clean-an-azure-storage-blob-container)

Comment: @h.o.m.a.n He want's to be able to delete specific blobs, not the whole thing though..

Comment: @CallumLinington you can modify this code to remove some files from container like this

'Parallel.ForEach(_cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(nameContainer).ListBlobs(),
                x =>
                {
                    if (list.Contains(((CloudBlob)x).Name))
                        ((CloudBlob)x).DeleteIfExists();
                });'

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is the code I use:

```
private CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;

public void DeleteFile(string uniqueFileIdentifier)
{
    this.AssertBlobContainer();

    var blob = this.blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueFileIdentifier);
    blob.DeleteIfExists();
}

private void AssertBlobContainer()
{
    // only do once
    if (this.blobContainer == null)
    {
        lock (this.blobContainerLockObj)
        {
            if (this.blobContainer == null)
            {
                var client = this.cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                this.blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(this.containerName.ToLowerInvariant());

                if (!this.blobContainer.Exists())
                {
                    throw new CustomRuntimeException("Container {0} does not exist in azure account", containerName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (this.blobContainer == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Blob Empty");
}
```

You can ignore the locking code if you know this isn't going to be accessed simultaneously

Obviously, you  have the `blobContainer` stuff sorted, so all you need is that `DeleteFile` method without the `this.AssertBlobContainer()`.

Comment: What is filename in var blob = this.blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);? I guess its uniqueFileIdentifier.

Comment: Good stuff, i suggest instead of calling Assert before every call, leverage singleton pattern through using a property with a backing field

Comment: take into account that this way you are not deleting its snapshots, just the blob itself

Comment: Can you update this answer? `CloudBlobContainer` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` has since been deprecated.

Comment: yeah sure - I'll do it next week - thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 17):

Remember [SDK v11 has been deprecated](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net), with [SDK v12](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet):

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
...
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("StorageConnectionString");
BlobContainerClient cont = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
cont.GetBlobClient("FileName.ext").DeleteIfExists();
```

Comment: I get the error: The specified resource name length is not within the permissible limits

Comment: @JNr this is another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328134/the-specified-resource-name-length-is-not-within-the-permissible-limits-azure-bl

Answer (score 3):

There's a method called DeleteIfExistis(). Returns true/false.

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
blob.DeleteIfExists();
```

Filename is ContainerName/FileName, if is inside folders you need to mention the folder too. Like ContainerName/AppData/FileName and will work.

Answer (score 2):

A single line code to perform deletion

```
private static async Task DeleteBLOBFile(string blobNamewithFileExtension)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobConnectionString,containerName,blobNamewithFileExtension);
            await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync();            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` to list the blobs and then cast it as `ICloudBlob` so that you can perform the `DeleteIfExistsAsync`. Below is the working sample function. Hope it helps.

```
public async Task < bool > PerformTasks() {
    try {
        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(StorageConnectionString, out CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount)) {
            var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(_blobContainerName);
            if (await cloudBlobContainer.ExistsAsync()) {
                BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
                var blobList = await cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(blobContinuationToken);
                var cloudBlobList = blobList.Results.Select(blb = >blb as ICloudBlob);
                foreach(var item in cloudBlobList) {
                    await item.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
                }
                return true;
            }
            else {
                _logger.LogError(ErrorMessages.NoBlobContainerAvailable);
            }
        }
        else {
            _logger.LogError(ErrorMessages.NoStorageConnectionStringAvailable);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<string> FileNameList = new List<string>();
FileNameList = fileName.Split(',').Where(t => t.ToString().Trim() != "").ToList();
CloudBlobClient client;
CloudBlobContainer container;
CloudBlockBlob blob;
string accessKey;
string accountName;
string connectionString;
accessKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountaccessKey");
accountName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountName");
connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountConnectionString");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
string containerName = tenantId;
container = client.GetContainerReference(containerName);

foreach(var file in FileNameList)
{
   blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file);
   blob.DeleteIfExists();
}
```

Comment: This code works but it's a mess. Unused variables, bad naming, etc. Please clean it up if you are going to submit it for others.