# The specified resource name length is not within the permissible limits Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am getting an error as "The specified resource name length is not within the permissible limits" when I try to upload a blob to my `Azure Storage Account`.

[image]

Below is my code.

```
private async Task UploadToAzureBlobStorage(string path, string fileName) {
    try {
        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(StorageConnectionString, out CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount)) {
            var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(path);
            var cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(path);
        }
        else {
            throw new CustomConfigurationException(CustomConstants.NoStorageConnectionStringSettings);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new CustomConfigurationException($ "Error when uploading to blob: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Anyone else have faced this same issue?

Comment: It's worth checking here for the rules around the naming of containers (and other resources): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2014/06/12/azure-storage-naming-rules/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes the error messages can be misleading. I was getting this error when I call the `await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(path);` and the reason behind this issue is that, I have provided an invalid parameter to the function `cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(path);`

[image]

This happened because of a recent change in the development. I was constantly concentrating on the `fileName` parameter in the `GetBlockBlobReference` function, as I thought the problem is with the blob name.

Unfortunately I was wrong and the **real issue was with the `blob container name` where it has some special characters in it**, so I had introduced a new parameter `schedule` to the existing function, and values of this parameter can be daily, weekly, monthly and these are the names of the containers I have configured in the Azure Blob Storage.

```
private async Task UploadToAzureBlobStorage(string schedule, string path, string fileName) {
    try {
        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(StorageConnectionString, out CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount)) {
            var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(schedule);
            var cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(path);
        }
        else {
            throw new CustomConfigurationException(CustomConstants.NoStorageConnectionStringSettings);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new CustomConfigurationException($ "Error when uploading to blob: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

[image]